# Appending new records at the top of datagridview from a datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have just inserted a bunch of queryresults into my datagridview as below:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = AVLQuery.ToList();
```

As I am going to track updates of the fields and append updated ones as new rows at the top of the datagridview, I just made a copy of above query to be comparable:

```
host = AVLQuery.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

then after the tick of the timer, here is the reconsidered query:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> AVLQ = (from AVL_D in DB_AxleLog.AsEnumerable()
                         join cId in checkpointID on AVL_D.check equals cId.check
                         select new
                         {
                             AVL_D.a;
                             AVL_D.b;
                             AVL_D.c;
                         }) as Enumerable<DataRow>
```

Here is the try to put that into a data table and the result of the comparison with the former values of the datagridview, i.e. `host`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    dt = AVLQ.CopyToDataTable();
}

catch(ArgumentNullException ex)
{
   // print stack trace
} 


var update = dt.asEnumerable().Intersect(host.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComprar.Default);
```

Now, the `update` result should be added at the top the datagridview

I just tested this:

```
dt.Rows.Add(update);
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

which doesn't work...

Does anybody have any idea to handle this case?

Comment: How does it 'not work' ? nothing happening? Error message? carsh? wrong data?..?

Comment: @TaW: I've an error, explaining my datatable has not enough space to get data.